# Possible to make CSS3 dynamic for a number of classes?

Tags: html, css

First off, im sorry if the following question is way to vague and unprecise, but this was my best explanation:

I've just started going trough HTML5 & CSS3. I'm drawing a line from point x1y1 to x2y2 with css3.

My question is, is there some way to dynamically call css3 code?

For example, say i have 10 names in a database, i want to place them inside the HTML doc and draw a line to each name from the center. Like a sun (the center) and the sunbeams (with the names at the end).

So for lets say name1 from the center of the "sun" points out 10degrees, the next beam could be 15 and the next after that 20 and so on..

2 days later the database might contain 20 names for which i want 20 sunbeams pointing out but without having to add 10 more .classnames stuff in my CSS3 doc

Is this even possible?

Thanks! :)

EDIT: Typo

Answer (score 0):

You can have another common class name for all beams say "beam_class" and define their properties in it, so you don't have to worry about the creating new classes for each beam.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do i specify individual properties dynamically this way? For example if each beam_class should be rotated 10 degrees diffrently

Comment: For that you can have id for each element or other classes also.